# Manipulating Images in Array to fadein and out on hover via Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to reference an array of images and everytime the user hovers over the image in the array, the image fades in. The image fades out when the user's mouse leaves the image.

the code that I have written is below but it does not seem to work. Help please

```
 var imagearray=[document.getElementById("one"),document.getElementById("two"),document.getElementById("three")]

$.each(imagrarray,function(){
 $.hover(function(){ $.fadeIn("slow");},function(){ $.fadeOut();
 });  });
```

html below:

```
<div id="faces" style=" overflow-y:hidden;  height:120px; display:inline-block; left: 20px ; position:relative; opacity:0.5" >
<div id="base" class="hidden" >
<li class=set1" style="display:inline;">
<img id="one" style="float:left" src="attachments/36508133/one.png?api=v2" height="100"width="52" /> 
<img id="two" style="float:left" src="attachments/36508133/two.png?api=v2" height="100"width="52"/>
<img id="three" style="float:left" src="attachments/36508133/three.png?api=v2" height="100" width="52"/> 

</li></div></div>
```

Comment: can you share the html as well

Comment: If you fade out the image, then how will you hover it again

Comment: hmm..everytime I move my mouse over the image, it fades in, when I move out, it fades out

Comment: how does that work... when you move out, if the image is faded out then how can you move the mouse in again

Comment: like https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/54v6v02r/1/ ?

Comment: Thanks Arun! yea...I realized...hm..after I did the opacity in -ine to 0.5. it works fine now. so it starts off at opacity 0.5 for all images. once the mouse moves in it fades to 1 and when the mouse moves out, it fades to the original 0.5.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you're not applying the hover to anything.

The *$.each* callback has two arguments, the index of the iteration over the given array and then the array item at the given index. You need to pass this to hover. So...

```
$.each(imagrarray,function(index, item){
 $(item).hover(function(){ $(this).fadeIn("slow");},function(){ $(this).fadeOut();
 });  });
```

Also, you weren't applying the fadeIn/out to anything either. In this case, *this* refers to the element returned by *$(item)*.

That said, the code could be refactored as you can see in Arun's jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are after is something like below, where you change the opacity of the elements

```js
$('.hover-set').hover(function() {
  $(this).fadeTo(500, 1);
}, function() {
  $(this).fadeTo(500, .5);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="faces" style=" overflow-y:hidden;  height:120px; display:inline-block; left: 20px ; position:relative; opacity:0.5">
  <div id="base" class="hidden">
    <li class="set1" style="display:inline;">
      <img id="one" class="hover-set" style="float:left" src="//placehold.it/64?text=1" height="100" width="52" />
      <img id="two" class="hover-set" style="float:left" src="//placehold.it/64?text=2" height="100" width="52" />
      <img id="three" class="hover-set" style="float:left" src="//placehold.it/64?text=3" height="100" width="52" />
    </li>
  </div>
</div>
```